# Group columns from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am pulling data from two tables (`t_Agent_Event_Detail` & `t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval`) in SQL Server on the same database which need to be joined on column `SkillTargetID`.  Running individual queries on each table works fine but when I attempt to join them, the output of `NumberofLogins` returns a count of all rows for each users' SkillTargetID from the `t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval` as opposed to the `Event` column in the `t_Agent_Event_Detail` table'.

```
select t_Agent_Event_Detail.SkillTargetID
,NumberofLogins = count(Event)
,LoggedIn = sum(t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval.LoggedOnTime)
,NotReady = sum(t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval.NotReadyTime)
,TalkTime = sum(t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval.HandledCallsTalkTime)
,WrapUp = sum(t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval.WorkReadyTime)

FROM
t_Agent_Event_Detail

LEFT JOIN
t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval 
ON t_Agent_Event_Detail.SkillTargetID = t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval.SkillTargetID 

WHERE
t_Agent_Event_Detail.DateTime > '2023-06-06'
and t_Agent_Event_Detail.Event = 1
and t_Agent_Event_Detail.SkillTargetID IN (5124,7813)
and t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval.DateTime > '2023-06-06'
and t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval.SkillTargetID IN (5124,7813)

GROUP BY t_Agent_Event_Detail.SkillTargetID, 
t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval.SkillTargetID
```

Output:

| SkillTargetID | NumberofLogins | LoggedIn | NotReady | TalkTime | WrapUp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5124 | 32 | 28584 | 10 | 31 | 60 |
| 7813 | 4 | 38 | 36 | 0 | 0 |

When running separate queries - Expected:

```
select
SkillTargetID
,LoggedInTime = sum(LoggedOnTime)
,NotReady = sum(NotReadyTime)
,TalkTime = sum(HandledCallsTalkTime)
,WrapUp = sum(WorkReadyTime) 
From t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval
where DateTime > '2023-06-06' and SkillTargetID IN (5124,7813)
GROUP BY SkillTargetID

select
       SkillTargetID
      ,NumberofLogins = count(Event)
from
t_Agent_Event_Detail
where
DateTime > '2023-06-06' and Event = 1
GROUP BY SkillTargetID
```

| SkillTargetID | LoggedIn | NotReady | TalkTime | WrapUp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5124 | 28584 | 10 | 31 | 60 |
| 7813 | 38 | 36 | 0 | 0 |

| SkillTargetID | NumberofLogins |
| --- | --- |
| 5124 | 1 |
| 7813 | 1 |

Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can go about correcting?

Sample Data

t_Agent_Event_Detail

| DateTime | SkillTargetID | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-06 06:01:48.000 | 5124 | 1 |
| 2023-06-06 06:01:53.000 | 5124 | 3 |
| 2023-06-06 09:14:56.000 | 7813 | 1 |
| 2023-06-06 09:15:00.000 | 7813 | 3 |
| 2023-06-06 09:15:15.000 | 7813 | 3 |
| 2023-06-06 09:15:15.007 | 7813 | 2 |

t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval

| SkillTargetID | LoggedOn | NotReadyTime | HandledCallsTalkTime | WorkReadyTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5124 | 792 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 5124 | 792 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 5124 | 900 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5124 | 900 | 0 | 31 | 60 |
| 5124 | 900 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Why do you `LET JOIN` to `t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval` when the column `DateTime` and `SkillTargetID` from that table **must** have a non-`NULL` value? It's impossible for either of those column to have a non-`NULL` value is no row was found.

Comment: Presumably, you have a one/many-to-many relationship. Therefore you need to *preaggegate* and then `INNER JOIN` (as the `LEFT JOIN` doesn't make sense where).

Comment: Sample data for the above output would help immensely

Comment: @ThomA - I am doing a left join due to the fact that information can populate in the Agent_Event_Detail table before it appears in the Agent_Skill_Group_Interval table

Comment: @Charlieface, question has been edited to include sample data

Comment: So why `WHERE t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval.DateTime > '2023-06-06'
and t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval.SkillTargetID IN (5124,7813)`? Either the `JOIN` is wrong or the `WHERE` is wrong.

Comment: Sample data doesn't fit your question. `DateTime` is missing from `t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval` and there is no data in that table for `7813`. But it looks like you need to move the conditions for `t_Agent_Skill_Group_Interval` to the `ON` clause instead of the `WHERE` https://dbfiddle.uk/UfeUn67c

Comment: @Charlieface, that would still be incorrect.  Trying to get Event=1 should only return a value of "1" in the results, as what is defined in the table.  Your results show 5.

Comment: I was just trying to show what I meant about the join. Well you can just pre-group both tables and join based on the grouping column https://dbfiddle.uk/N00J7gwi Like I said, your joins are unclear, as are your expected results

Comment: That worked for me.  Thanks!  Curious to know why the condition/join wasn't working as expected though.

Comment: Because you were cross joining one giant table then aggregating afterwards. As I said, I can't show exactly what you are trying because the sample data and expected results don't seem to match, and the use of the `LEFT JOIN` as opposed to `INNER` is unclear